What exactly does 散々 mean?

散々上司の愚痴を語りあったとおもったら

What exactly does 散々 mean here? From the example sentences that I've read, it seems like a adverb meaning terrible, but the English fan translation translates it as "I though we were just having a good time complaining about are bosses, when..."
So I'm thinking that either 散々 was dropped in the translation, or it has the meaning of completely/utterly here as defined in weblio.jp

１ 物事の程度が著しいさま。「若いころ—に世話になった人」(also, does に here mean that it's treated as a な-adjective in the adverbial case?)

But it seems like this meaning is significantly rarer, so I'm not really sure. By the way, the kanji for it  means scattered, but it jisho says that it's an archaic meaning of 散々. How did it even get it's modern meaning, and is the scattered meaning still understood by Japanese people?
I'm so confused, can't anyone explain it to me?

Today, 散々 is used in two different ways.

When used as a na-adjective, it means "terrible", "miserable", etc.

When used as a standalone adverb (without に), it means "much more than enough", "thoroughly", "endlessly", etc. It usually emphasizes the length of time spent rather than the severity of the result. It doesn't necessarily carry a negative connotation like "excessively" or "overly". It's commonly used with some adverse or undesirable result (i.e., it's often followed by けど, のに, etc), but this is not a strict rule.


For example, 散々に怒られた means someone was scolded terribly or miserably, whereas 散々怒られた (without に) means someone was scolded for an (unnecessarily) long time. 散々遊んだ is natural, but 散々に遊んだ sounds awkward.
Similarly, 散々上司の愚痴を語りあう means to complain about the boss extensively, for a long time, to the point where it may be considered excessive. Whether "have a good time" is a good translation depends on the context. 散々に上司の愚痴を語りあった would normally mean they made harsh remarks about their boss.
I don't know much about its etymology, but I think it's an expression that links the image of something shattering or breaking apart with a terrible outcome.
